# How to make a box-shadow with an outline but no fill in CSS

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to convert this design from Illustrator into a UI element in vanilla HTML and CSS (design was given to me from a designer to recreate). I need the inner box with the cyan and white outlines to be clickable, like a button, but not the outer light blue area that surrounds the text.
[image: Image trying to recreate]
Originally, I figured I could just use a box shadow to create the second, offset white border, but the box-shadow will only be shown in the bottom and right edges of the box, and won't show it inside the cyan border.

I was thinking that maybe I could do another DIV with absolute positioning to offset it, but I'm not sure how to choose the size for that second DIV as I want this button to scale based on viewport width.

How would I go about doing this? I want to avoid the option of saving it as an SVG or image as it would then be hard to create the "a" element to fit only the text portion with a clickable link.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48662661/8620333

Comment: So you only want the click on the "borders"? seems odd and unexpected by users to me

Comment: Please update with the HMTL and CSS that you have tried here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it like below:

```css
button {
  font-size: 30px;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  border: solid #fff;
  border-width: 0 5px 5px 0;
  box-shadow:
    -5px -5px 0 cyan,
    -5px -5px 0 inset cyan,
     5px  5px 0 inset #fff;
  background: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}

body {
  background: lightblue;
}
```

```html
<button>Click here </button>
```

Comment: Visually this seems to suffice; I do wonder about confusing "clickable parts" comments the OP has though including the "create the "a" element to fit" portion - not your fault there though

Comment: This is great, I never knew you could do box shadows on a per-side basis, thank you! Sorry about the clickable parts comment, this is correct in that I just needed the part with the borders as well as the area inside the borders to be clickable!